# Cannot find function for these actuals

Tags: vhdl, fpga, synthesis, asic

My compiler is giving me these errors:

# Error: COMP96_0305: SUBONE_MODULE_VHDL.vhd : (93, 23): Cannot find function "TO_INTEGER" for these actuals.

# Error: COMP96_0138: SUBONE_MODULE_VHDL.vhd : (93, 23): The index types in the reference to the array object are incompatible with its range type.**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;

use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.all;


entity SUBONE_MODULE_VHDL is
 port(
     addr : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 downto 0);
     clk : in STD_LOGIC;
     dout : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 downto 0)
     );
end SUBONE_MODULE_VHDL;


architecture SUBONE_MODULE_VHDL of SUBONE_MODULE_VHDL is     

type ROM_Array is array (0 to 31) 
of std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);


constant Content: ROM_Array := (
    0 => "10011",       -- Suppose ROM has 
    1 => "00000",       -- prestored value
    2 => "00001",       -- like this table
    3 => "00010",               --
    4 => "00011",       --
    5 => "00100",               --
    6 => "00101",       --
    7 => "00110",               --
    8 => "00111",               --
    9 => "01000",               --
   10 => "01001",       --
   11 => "01010",           --
   12 => "01011",           --
   13 => "01100",       --
   14 => "01101",       --
   15 => "01110",       --
   16 => "01111",       --
   17 => "01110",       --
   18 => "01110",       --
   19 => "01110",       --
   20 => "01110",       --
   21 => "00000",       --
   22 => "00001",       --
   23 => "00010",       --
   24 => "00011",       --
   25 => "00100",       --
   26 => "00101",       --
   27 => "00110",       --
   28 => "00111",       --
   29 => "01000",       --
   30 => "01001",       --
   31 => "01010",       --
 OTHERS => "00000"
);       

begin
    process(clk, addr) 
    variable addr : integer := 0;   
    begin
        if( clk'event and clk = '1' ) then
            dout <= Content(TO_INTEGER(addr));
        end if;
    end process;

end SUBONE_MODULE_VHDL;
```

Answer (score 1):

The port `addr` is a `std_logic_vector` and can not be cast directly to `integer`. cast it to `unsigned` or `signed` first:

> dout <= Content(TO_INTEGER(SIGNED(addr)));

EDIT: There is also a conflict with the variable named `addr` and the port of same name.
Therefore, renaming the variable to e.g. `addr_var` will fix the problem. In this case no type cast is necessary.

> variable addr_var : integer := 0;
>   ...
>   dout <= Content(addr_var);

Which of the two solutions is the right one for you depends on which `addr` you intented to use while accessing `CONTENT`.

Generally, reusing the exact same name for ports, signals or variables is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

There is a name clash between "addr" (the integer variable, for which TO_INTEGER is obviously not defined) and "addr" (the port) which is a "bag of bits" and as such, again has no TO_INTEGER method. If the latter were Unsigned (or Signed) types from numeric_std, or you cast the STD_LOGIC_VECTOR to unsigned, then you would have something numeric on which TO_INTEGER would work.

My preference would be to eliminate the variable "addr" and to make the "addr" port Unsigned, or even Natural (a non-negative form of Integer).

Incidentally, "addr" need not (and should not) be part of the process sensitivity list.